# Is there any way to control the useEffect result with API request which is frequently invoked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I wrote some code which return search results as per keyword user type, and wanna make sure that search results should be accordance with user's latest input.

Hi I am noob in React(technically in frontend).
I wrote some code which return search results as per keyword user typed.

As below, every time the keyword has changed, useEffect is invoked, and search results is updated along with API request's response.

Although search results should be accordance with user's latest input, currently it doesn't.

The problem is that API request response time is variable and it doesn't guarantee the order useEffect is called.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const useSuggestions = () => {
  //user's input, 'keyword' for search
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  //search results which renders on browser
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let didCancel = false;
    const fetchSuggestions = async word => {
      if (!didCancel) {
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/autocomplete?keyword=${word}`).catch(e => {
          console.error(e);
          return [];
        });
        setSuggestions(response.data);
      }
    };
    fetchSuggestions(query);
    return () => {
      didCancel = true;
    };
  }, [query]);

  const handleChange = e => {
    setQuery(e.target.value);
  };

  return {
    suggestions,
    handleChange,
  };
};

export default useSuggestions;
```

For example, although if user's latest input is 'Diamond', I expect the API response of 'Diamond' is set to search result.
However the API response of 'Diamon' or 'Diamo' is set to search result indeed.

Is there any way to control the order of useEffect invocation?

Pls ask for any ambiguous description.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should use: https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation, `cancelToken` is created for exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a timeout so that the search doesnt occur as you type but rather with a 1 or 2 seconds delay. Maybe something like this will help:

Add this to your code:

```
var timeout = null;
function delayedFetch(val) {
  if (timeout) {  
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
     setQuery(val);
  }, 2000);
}
```

and update your `handleChange` function to

```
const handleChange = e => {
   delayedFetch(e.target.value);
};
```